# Blackberry Webworks delete webstorage

Tags: blackberry-webworks, web-storage

How can i delete webstorage data?

I am using HTML5 db to store app Data for my webworks blackberry app. The problem is when i delete the app the app data is still there. If i install the app again the old data is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the database manually via the "File" explorer. I found my created database in `/Device/BlackBerry/system/appdata/rim/webstorage/(application name)`. Or you can simply upgrade your database version so that the newer one will be used instead of the old one.

Comment: Thank you, but I want it to be automatic so that users don't have to care about deleting app data. I think it is not possible.

Comment: you can delete the database using phonegap API on the first launch of the application.